# Which is more performant: Calling array.prototype.push with all elements at once or push each element once?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I.e. compare the two following functions:

```
var e1 = {a:1};
var e2 = {b:2};
var e3 = {c:3};

var test1 = function() {
    var a = [];
    a.push(e1, e2, e3);
};

var test2 = function() {
    var a = [];
    a.push(e1);
    a.push(e2);
    a.push(e3);
};
```

Is any one more performant or are they equal in that respect?

**EDIT**: The reason I ask is that I'm working with a 3rd party lib that uses the second approach extensively, and I suspected that it was because of the desire to optimize, since it didn't make the code more readable.

Comment: Go to jsperf.com and find out.

Comment: Just don't worry about it, use the first one, it's shorter. Microptimization is pointless.

Comment: In general, fewer function calls are likely to be better. But unless you're pushing thousands of elements, the difference will probably be negligible.

Comment: the reason why I want to know is that I'm working with 3rd party scripts that use the second form exclusively, and I'm curious if it's because of performance it is like that.

Comment: Put it in a loop go through 1000-10000 loops and test it with the date object to see which one is the fastest and then let us know here ;)

Comment: How many elements in your array? In practice, pushing elements in the array is hardly going to be the bottleneck, JS arrays are freaking fast if you stay consistent (i.e. keep the same data type and only insert sequentially). Also, insert standard warning about permature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practical answer is - to all intents and purposes, *they are the same*.  Unless your program consists solely of pushing elements into an array, you are not likely to see any noticeable difference in performance between either of these methods.

You should therefore choose whichever is most natural, understandable and maintainable for the humans that read the source code.

(And this is true for any other performance-related questions, too.  Write *sensible* code, and only optimise once you've measured that the particular block of code is causing an undesirable delay in your application as a whole.)

Answer (score 1):

Using a naive approach to measure the performance, <strike>it seems that using the 'test2' methodology is slightly faster:</strike>

```
var e0 = {a:1};
var e1 = {a:1};
var e2 = {a:1};
var e3 = {a:1};
var e4 = {a:1};
var e5 = {a:1};
var e6 = {a:1};
var e7 = {a:1};
var e8 = {a:1};
var e9 = {a:1};
var ref = [e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9];

var test1 = function() {
    var a = [];
    a.push(e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9);
};

var test2 = function() {
    var a = [];
    a.push(e0);
    a.push(e1);
    a.push(e2);
    a.push(e3);
    a.push(e4);
    a.push(e5);
    a.push(e6);
    a.push(e7);
    a.push(e8);
    a.push(e9);
};

function t1 () {
    var tStart = new Date().valueOf();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test1()
    }
    var tEnd = new Date().valueOf();
    var tDelta = tEnd - tStart;

    console.log(tDelta);        
}

function t2 () {
    var tStart = new Date().valueOf();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test2()
    }
    var tEnd = new Date().valueOf();
    var tDelta = tEnd - tStart;

    console.log(tDelta);        
}

console.log('t1'); t1();
console.log('t2'); t2();
```

which outputs:

```
t1
483
t2
523
```

However, the 'test1' approach is far more readable, IMO. Personally I would use this approach simply because of that, as I am generally not worried about javascript array performance.

EDIT: Indeed I forgot one element in the t2 function. Revised the test and results. It seems the more readable form is also *slightly* (insignificantly) faster.

Comment: You're missing a `a.push(e0);` in `test2()`, so that's why it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

Less function calls in JavaScript itself are typically faster, because in that way the bulk of the work can be performed in the engine itself.

This [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/array-push-speed) gives an idea what kind of efficiency can be achieved.

Note that this is of course a very isolated case, so don't be surprised when it doesn't matter in the end :)

**Update**

Interestingly, Firefox shows a different result; multiple `push` statements are executed faster. I'm not sure why that would be.